# Maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is $(5, x^2+3)$ a maximal or prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

I guess $(5, x^2+3)$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, therefore a prime ideal. Can anyone give me some hint?

Comment: It is easy to check if $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2+3)=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,x^2+3)$ is an integral domain (so that $(5,x^2+3)$ is a prime ideal). Since it is finite, if it is integral then it is a field, and $(5,x^2+3)$ is a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you can go about it. If you quotient a ring $R$ by a maximal ideal, you will get a field. Now $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,x^2+3)$ can be computed successively, i.e. 
$$
\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,x^2+3)=(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5))/(x^2+3). 
$$
Now $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5)=(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]$; can you go from here?

Edit (follow up): If you like this type of thing, you can show the stronger statement: a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has the form $(p,f(x))$, where $p$ is prime and $f(x)$ is irreducible mod $p$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain the isomorphism between the quotients? Is it followed by some isomorphism theorems?

Comment: My class just started so I will get back to this but yeah, the isomorphism theorems should work

Comment: @user335468 You can really think to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,x^2+3)$ as the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with its addition and multiplication and two more rules : $5 = 0$ and $x^2+3 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation on the isomorphism:
\begin{align}\mathbf Z[X]/\bigl(p, f(X)\bigr)&\simeq \mathbf Z[X]/(p\mathbf Z[X])/\bigl(p, f(X)\bigr)/(p\mathbf Z[X])&&\text{(3rd isomorphism theorem)}\\
&\simeq \mathbf Z[X]/(p\mathbf Z[X])/f(X)\cdot\bigl(\mathbf Z[X]/(p\mathbf Z[X])\bigr)\\
&\simeq (\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)[X]/\bigl(f(X)\cdot(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)[X]\bigr)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your explanation